# Magento2 not able to get & save customer custom attribute

Tags: custom, customer-attribute, magento2.1.5

I am using Magento 2.1.5, and created custom attribute for customer and trying to get & set the values of custom attribute but didn't get custom attribute in customer collection and as well as set also.

add custom attribute:

```
 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Sample Attribute',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'required' => true,
            'default' => '0',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'system' => false,
            'position' => 100
        ]
    );
    $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');
    $sampleAttribute->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
        ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
    );
    $sampleAttribute->save();
```

Get custom attribute value :

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load('1');
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($customerRepository->getData());
```

Comment: I have updated code. Please let me know if you have query after using below code.

Comment: Rakesh, am facing same issue when am loading in controller & am getting 500 error

Comment: Have you remove var/generation folder?please check again i have updated answer.

Comment: Rakesh sorry to say, its generation issue . am able to get the getCustomAttribute. can't save the data with setCustomAttribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call below class in `__consturct()` function in your controller  file and get and set value from customer.

```
  <?php
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
    {        
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCustomerAttribute(){
        $customerId = 1;
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

        //get customer custom attribute value
        $customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attribute');

        //set customer custom attribute value
        $sample_attribute = 2;
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('sample_attribute',$sample_attribute);
       try {                
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Remove **var/generation** folder.clear cache.

Comment: I am trying to get at controller but \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository, this is not working at contoller

Comment: It's working, but why can't use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository with getById and save method's

Comment: can you please clarify my query ?

Comment: Sorry, I havent try with those method so i cant say more info, Use API method to save/update/get of customer object. its helpful for future with new major version released and if any update is made then its made inside model file so best way to use API method to get/set entity.

Comment: You can close this question so other users have useful in future.

Comment: I didn't get the close button for this question

Comment: You can close this question after click on true sign below the up and down arrow above the answer in left side.